# Scrapy hxs.select returning []

Tags: python, scrapy

I run the following and it works fine:

```
hxs.select('//h1').extract()
```

However this

```
hxs.select('//div[@class="ClassName"]/text()').extract()
```

returns `[]`.

Is my syntax wrong? I'm unsure why the `div` class isn't working (it's definitely there!).

Comment: Could you show a sample of the document you're scraping that you think matches your query path?

Comment: how much context would you need? - the class appears like this:  <div class="ClassName"><h1>ProductName 1234566 962 96-2-120 Descriptive Text / 120M</h1></div>    thanks by the way!

Comment: Then the result makes sense - there's no text content in the `div` -- it's all part of the `h1` - what are you trying to extract?

Comment: there are 3 specific divs on each page that I want to extract.  I don't suppose the h1 tags might be interfering with the process somehow? should I account for them in the hxs.select?

Comment: If they're all `//div.../h1` - then use that - otherwise, it's hard to tell - at the moment, there's no actual content in the div (but there is in the div's children - eg: the h1)

Comment: thanks for your help Jon - I tried out firepath, and got this result as the xpath: .//*[@id='Class']/div[1]/div[2]/h1

Comment: just re-read your second comment. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without the html is a difficult to answers this.

I recommend to use firefox + xpath addon , I use [firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/) to evaluate xpaths on webpages. Check for other addons that allow you to create xpath from firebug view.

Your syntax seems to be correct.

Comment: thanks, I tried firepath and it shows this as the xpath:   .//*[@id='Class']/div[1]/div[2]/h1

Comment: unsure why it's just 'Class' as opposed to ClassName, which the CSS suggests.

Comment: unfortunately when I substitute ClassName with Class, I get the same [] response.